# linux fedor, pyautogui, mouse, мышка не реагирует

Tags: linux, pyautogui, fedora, мышь

Такая история, захотел я на линуксе написать простенький кликер:

import keyboard

import mouse

import time

isClicking = False

def set_clicker():

global isClicking

if isClicking:

isClicking = False

print('Disabled')

else:

isClicking = True

print('Enabled')

keyboard.add_hotkey('Alt + Z', set_clicker)

while True:

if isClicking:

mouse.double_click(button='left')

импортировал все библиотеки, линукс немного поламался, через pip3 библиотеки устанавливались но не работали, через sudo dnf получилось установить и ошибок не выдавало, но мышь не реагировала, клики не происходили. Я обратился к чатугпт пообщался с ним, повписывал кучу команд в терминал, одна из которых xhost +, ничего не работало, мышь просто никак не реагировала.
Я по совету того же бота перешёл на другую либу pyautogui:
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.PAUSE = 1.5

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

pyautogui.position()

print(pyautogui.position())

pyautogui.moveTo(1920/2,1080/2)

недописав до конца код просто ради интереса его включил, чтоб посмотреть. Но симптомы все те же, все библиотеки установлены tkinter, devel, scopt, включен доступ к экрану через xhost +, но мышка вообще не реагирует. При том, что строчка в этом коде выводит в терминал позицию курсора Point(x=877, y=1070).

Вообще не понимаю что не так и как себе помочь.